# Login system to json with gson as parser doesn't work

Tags: java, gson

It keeps printing "unsuccessful login" even though the json file it is reading from actually contains `{"beansly":"beans"}` on the first line and the only line.

Is there any way to have gson parse the key value pair and return the value of the key "beansly"?

in login()

```java
private static void login(String username, String password) throws IOException {
        JsonElement jsonData = readOrCreateNew(new File(".\\data.json")).get(username);
        String passwordData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, String.class);
        if (passwordData == password) {
            System.out.println("Login successful");
        }
        else if (passwordData != password) {
            System.out.println("Login unsuccessful");
        }
    }
```

in readOrCreateNew()

```java
private static JsonObject readOrCreateNew(File f) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (f.exists() && f.length() > 0) {
            // Using "try" with parentheses to automatically close the BufferedReader
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                return gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
            }
        }
        return new JsonObject();
    }
```

Comment: You probably should use if(password.equals(passwordData)) and don't use ==
See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java

Comment: @R.Groote Thanks for the suggestion! Still keeps giving me "Login unsuccessful" though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `JsonElement` you do not need to convert it to `String` using `Gson`. Just get `String` by calling [getAsString()](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsString--):

```
String passwordData = jsonData.getAsString();
if (passwordData.equals(password)) {
    System.out.println("Login successful");
} else {
    System.out.println("Login unsuccessful");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, finally my program is complete, i'll also remember what you have taught me so far! Thanks again :)